# Stripe payment slows down booking page

Tags: plugins

I have WordPress 5.5.3 with Elementor. When try to check the availability of the rooms and this page slowing down to about 30 seconds to open my page /?booking
q.stripe link that failed to load

```
https://q.stripe.com/?event=stripejs-error&type=FailedMFrameLoad&key=undefined&timestamp=1604928371&payment_user_agent=stripe.js%2F6c4e062
```

I try to disable the stripe plugin, but Elementor need it.
How can i remove these java from every page:

```
<script type=’text/javascript’ src=’https://js.stripe.com/v2/?ver=5.4.4′></script>
```

and that one also:

```
<script type=’text/javascript’ src=’https://bridge.paymill.com/?ver=5.4.4′></script>
```

How to fix this problem? Any ideas?
Thank you!

Comment: You should find the `wp_enqueue_script()` commands for each of these and call [`wp_dequeue_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dequeue_script/) for each one with the same handle the enqueue is using.

Comment: But it would be better to try and work out why these scripts are being added - do you have a checkout link on every page? - and solve the cause not the symptom. If it's Elementor doing this you may need to ask them for help.

Comment: You should also probably find out why the stripe script is failing to load and taking so long to do so. If the script inclusion looks sensible and matches Stripe's developer documentation then you could ask their customer service to help understand that - presumably you do have pages where you need it to load successfully?